# pseudo selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a pseudo selector or method to detect a `<section>` tag with an id. I.E. `<section id="no_display">`?

I have a header and it has a bottom margin of 35px. However, I don't want to apply the bottom margin on one page, but I want to apply it on all others.

Is there a method to detect an id and not apply the margin?

```
<header>
    //stuff here
</header>
<section id="no_display">
    //other stuff here
</section>
```

So, if `<header>` is immediately followed by `section id="no_display"`, don't apply the bottom margin

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: In this case you want a preceding sibling selector, not a pseudo-class. And no, that doesn't exist.

Comment: @BoltClock - ok, thanks. Any other CSS ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative margin for your `section` to compensate `margin-bottom` of its previous sibling element:

```css
#no_display {
    margin-top: -35px;
}
```

Comment: That is an obvious answer that I completely overlooked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't usually use [pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-classes) to express relationships between two or more elements; you use [combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selector-syntax). In this case, you want a preceding-sibling combinator. Unfortunately, [that doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector).

What does exist are following-sibling combinators. Since you really only want the margin to be there if `section` doesn't have that ID, you can switch the bottom margin on `header` out for a top margin on `section`, and use an override rule for when it does have the ID to remove the margin from it:

```
header + section {
    margin-top: 35px;
}

header + section#no_display {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

(You really don't need a selector like `header + section#no_display` since the ID alone is specific enough, but doing this helps me tell at a glance that the second rule is related to the first.)

Comment: Haven't read all the way. My bad. Your answer is the right one so I take down my imaginary hat :)